# Strange padding while using UIWebView/WKWebView

Tags: ios, css, uiwebview, wkwebview

[image: sides padding]

On emulator and real device I get this white padding in the left and right sides of the page. Also I would like to remove top bar too. I have UIWebView/WKWebView on the Main.storyboard:
[image: Constrains]

I tried to set -20 value of constrains but it gives nothing.
Here the code:

```
 @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;

        let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.google.ru/");
        var req = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
        webView.loadRequest(req);

    }
```

and also I tried add `body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }` to mine own page before I started testing on google. I checked Safari - it's fit google pictures perfect. 
So nothing of what I tried didn't help me. How can I remove those left/right white padding in WKWebView?

Comment: Looks like your leading/trailing constraints are relative to the margin. Make them not relative to margin and see what happens.

Answer (score 14):

Looks like out of box WKWebView sets a margin on the body tag.  You can remove this by creating a WKWebViewConfiguration and adding initializing with the configuration including the body style with margin 0.

```
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
let bodyStyle = "body { margin:0; }"
let source = "var node = document.createElement(\"style\"); node.innerHTML = \"\(bodyStyle)\";document.body.appendChild(node);"

let script = WKUserScript(
            source: source,
            injectionTime: .AtDocumentEnd,
            forMainFrameOnly: false
        )

config.userContentController.addUserScript(script)
webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectZero, configuration: config)
```

Or the quick and dirty way would be to just add an inline style to you view. (I haven't tried this way)

Comment: I was loading the html source myself in the webview.
Adding the style tag and setting the margin to zero worked for me.
    <style>
    body{margin:0;}
    </style>

Comment: This solution can also work by implementing `self.webview.evaluateJavaScript("var node = document.createElement(\"style\"); node.innerHTML = \"body { margin:0; }\";document.body.appendChild(node);", completionHandler: nil)` in webview did finish load.

Comment: Thanks. I was experiencing the same but did no find anything about it in the official documentation

Answer (score 1):

Use this line to remove padding from top.

self.webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
self.webView.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never